# Cómo realizar una buena depuracion y pruebas unitarias en ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hace poco me llamo la curiosidad y quisiera contar con su apoyo para resolver esta pregunta: En `ReactJS` se crea componentes, y hasta ahí, todo bien, sin embargo cuando se agrega la lógica a desarrollar... Cómo realizar una buena `depuración`? Y cuando se necesite realizar `pruebas unitarias`, cómo hacer testing de ello?

Aquí un ejemplo de `ReactJS`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>
    <script src="build/react.js"></script>
    <script src="build/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="example"></div>
  <script type="text/babel">
  ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('example')
  );
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Creo que deberías echarle un vistazo a [enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme) y a [herramientas de prueba de React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html)

Comment: Para las pruebas una de las alternativas que conseguí hacer funcionar rápidamente fue [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/). Muy sencilla de utilizar y con buena documentación. Me vino genial un [tutorial en español escrito por Jeison Higuita](https://platzi.com/blog/react-jest-componentes/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parte de las buenas practicas de React consiste en aislar el funcionamiento de sus componentes.

Cuando hablamos de lógica es común que esta implique el uso de varios componentes, y aquí es cuando la depuración y el mantenimiento del código puede complicarse.

La filosofía de React dicta que es solo la V de MVC, por lo que en teoria podrias aplicar cualquier arquitectura y patron de desarrollo. Basado en esto tomemos las siguientes consideraciones.

1. Un componente de React, no deberia tener lógica como tal, solo debería recibir los datos que debe mostrar, recordemos que es solo la vista.
2. Un componente deberia funcionar aislado y no debe conocer conoce información ni "hablar" directamente con otro componente.

Ahora, existen arquitecturas que funcionan especialmente bien con React, como lo es [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html), que al tener flujos de datos unidireccionales, permiten manejar el concepto de componentes muy bien, ya que el componente solo recibe los datos que debe mostrar, como lo nombre anteriormente.

Respecto al tema de pruebas unitarias:

Como cada componente debe funcionar aislado, existen excelentes herramientas para probarlos como [React Storybook](https://github.com/kadirahq/react-storybook)

Para correr pruebas en teoria deberia ser igual que el resto de los test unitarios, por ejemplo puedes diseñarlos en base al Storybook, y correrlos individualmente, así detectas errores en el componente específico y el flujo de trabajo seria mas rapido.

Actualización:
Encontre [Crypress](https://www.cypress.io/), se ve muy bueno para hacer testing, parece basarse en la filosofía de componentes.